# 'void *' to 'void (*) (bool)' Errors with pointers compiling files in c with a c ++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

First of all, thank you to whoever is reading and to whom you can respond.

This part of code, is part of an interface library gui, totally written in c.

But I'm tempted to compile these written files in c, with a c ++ compiler to be able to integrate into a program I'm doing with wxwidgets.

Within the c files, I have several function calls that have as arguments, pointers to other functions.

```
 typedef struct {
      void (*fchd_ptr)(bool);   
      uint16_t xpos;         
      uint16_t ypos;          
        ...
        ...
}BUTTON_t;

void BT_SetHandler(BUTTON_t* ptr, void* fchd_ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return;

    ptr->fchd_ptr =  fchd_ptr;  // OK in C, ERROR In C++
}
```

When I try to compile in C ++, I get this error.

```
ptr-> fkt_ptr = fkt_ptr;
// error: invalid conversion from 'void *' to 'void (*) (bool)' [-fpermissive]
```

If I cast an explicit cast.

```
ptr-> fkt_ptr = (bool *) fkt_ptr;
// error: can not convert 'bool *' to 'void (*) (bool)' in assignment
```

Any help, and explanation how to solve it will be welcome.

Comment: How to solve it is to add fuel to the fire and add a bunch of explicit casts everywhere. This is very fragile, and type-unsafe. An even better solution is to rewrite the whole thing in typesafe C++.

Comment: C++ has stronger typing rules with respect to what you can do with a `void*` It demands that you acknowledge that you're doing something dodgy with a cast.

Comment: Are you really explicitly casting to `bool*`? Seems like you should cast to `(void (*)(bool))` instead...

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, I know that if everything was in C ++ it would be right, but I try to reuse the code in c, because what I'm trying to do is a RAD tool, ie drag and drop.
So, I need the c code, as this will be used by the final application in c.

Comment: You should compile the C files in C.  (Maybe you are unaware that compiled C files can be linked into a C++ project)

Comment: hit, I applied (void (*) (bool)), and the error stopped.
You could explain (void (*) (bool)), so I understand what happens.

Comment: `void (*fchd_ptr)(bool)` declares a pointer to a function that accepts a `bool` parameter and returns `void`

Comment: M.M, I was going in that direction, compile in c and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explicit cast is wrong. You cast to `bool *` (pointer to object of type `bool`), when you really should be casting to `void (*)(bool)` (pointer to function taking a `bool` and returning nothing).<sup>1</sup>

If you replace that line by

```
ptr->fchd_ptr = (void (*)(bool)) fchd_ptr;
```

it will compile in both C and C++.

---

If possible, however, you should try to compile your C code in C only - while we might get this one thing working, the two languages are not always fully compatible, and you may well run into trouble down the road. Generally, it is possible to compile C code separately from the C++ parts. If you use [`extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c#1041880) in your header files, you can simply link the C++ objects and the C objects together, or keep the C part in a separate library (static or dynamic).

Additionally, I would recommend reworking the C API so that it really takes a function pointer all the way through if that is at all possible. Aliasing through `void *` is ugly and can lead to some really nasty bugs and crashes if you pass in the wrong pointer type.

---

<sup>1</sup> Function pointers are generally very different from object pointers, and it is implementation-defined whether you are even allowed to cast between the two. Here, you want a pointer to a function, not a pointer to an object (like `bool*` would be a pointer to an object of type `bool`) so that you can call it later. You can see in your code sample that `void (*fchd_ptr)(bool)` is the declaration of the variable that you assign to, which makes `void (*)(bool)` its type. If you find the notation somewhat confusing, [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org) is a great way to deal with those convoluted array, pointer and function pointer names that come from C.

Comment: *recommend reworking the C API so that it really takes a function pointer* -- this will avoid the need of a cast for assignment.

Comment: jxh, Could you give an example?
How would you do with the code example above?

Comment: Basically the idea is to replace `void *fchd_ptr` in the function signature with `void (*fchd_ptr)(bool)` - the same function pointer type that you need later. That lets you avoid the cast, and the errors that can happen with `void *`

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature of the function to accept a function pointer that matches the type expected by `ptr->fchd_ptr`. Then, you would not need to use a cast to complete the assignment.

Based on your question, this would be:

```
void BT_SetHandler(BUTTON_t* ptr, void (*fchd_ptr)(bool))
```

However, if you are not sure what the type is for `ptr->fchd_ptr`, you can make the compiler figure it out for you. Previously, this could only be done with a template function and it would derive a type based on what was passed into the function call at compile time. However, C++.11 provdes `decltype`, which allows you to enforce the type you want for the function parameter, rather than letting the compiler deduce one from callers of the function.

```
void BT_SetHandler(BUTTON_t* ptr, decltype(ptr->fchd_ptr) fchd_ptr)
```

This is fine so long as you are intent on compiling your code with a C++ compiler.